# Trigger Para Actualizar Stock en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

Que tal, me encuentro realizando un sistema de préstamo de herramientas y necesito actualizar el Stock de los productos cada vez que entre o salga un producto del almacén, no he usado triggers en mySQL y esto esta siendo algo complicado.

Este es el Trigger que tengo escrito, el trigger debera sera disparado cada que se inserta un nuevo registro en la tabla "INCLUYE" actualizado "STOCK" en la tabla de "PRODUCTO", pero cada que sucede esto muestra un error de que la columna no ha sido encontrada.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `DemoDos`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `DemoDos`.`restarStock` AFTER INSERT 
ON `INCLUYE` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Update `PRODUCTO` set `STOCK` = `STOCK` - `New.CANTIDAD_ENTREGADA`
where `ID_PRODUCTO` = `ID_PRODUCTO`;
END$$
```

Estas son las tablas es cuestión.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme y de antemano gracias!

Comment: where `ID_PRODUCTO` = `ID_PRODUCTO` esto esta bien? y cual es la columna que dice que no encontro?

Comment: @gbianchi lo escribo asi, dado que si coloco "where INCLUYE.ID_PRODUCTO = PRODUCTO.ID_PRODUCTO" sigue marcando el mismo error "Unknown column 'INCLUYE.ID_PRODUCTO' in 'field list'" e incluso pensé que me marcaría el error de que el nombre de la columna es ambiguo, pido ayuda ya que puede que el trigger este mal escrito..

Comment: no es NEW.ID_producto = producto.Id_producto?

Comment: y por favor, aclara bien el error, cual es la columna que protesta. Lo mismo que escribiste en tu comentario...

Comment: @gbianchi Ya lo intente de esa manera también y marca el mismo error con diferencia de que la columna que no encuentra es otra, ahora el error es este: INSERT INTO INCLUYE (ID_PRESTAMO, ID_PRODUCTO, CANTIDAD_ENTREGADA, CANTIDAD_DEVUELTA) VALUES (1,3,5,0) Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'NEW.ID_PRODUCTO' in 'where clause' 0.063 sec

Comment: probaste todas las columnas sin las comillas simples? a simple vista parece todo bien.

Comment: Claro, @gbianchi he probado sin comillas, cambiando el orden de las columnas, haciendo la resta entre paréntesis, etcétera y como te digo, cada que hago una modificación el nombre de la columna que no encuentra es diferente

Comment: ok, entonces vas a tener que agregar todas esas pruebas y los errores, si no estoy tirando sin saber que hiciste o dejaste de hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya logre solucionar el problema, agrego el código del trigger correcto:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER DemoDos.restarStock 
AFTER INSERT ON INCLUYE FOR EACH ROW
Update PRODUCTO
set PRODUCTO.STOCK = PRODUCTO.STOCK - NEW.CANTIDAD_ENTREGADA
where PRODUCTO.ID_PRODUCTO = NEW.ID_PRODUCTO;
```

Comment: oye bro, y cuando se elimine  esa venta como hago para retornar ese valor eliminado al stock?

Comment: Podrías explicar con mas detalle cual es tu problema? @ManuelMorales

Comment: total stock 10, _ingresamos 5_ total stock 5, _siempre no, que eran 6_ total stock 4_como hago eso_ ? supongo que es un trigger update

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que quieres revertir el stock en caso de que haya algún error al registrar la venta, si es así deberías de crear un trigger onUpdate en la tabla de venta... @ManuelMorales

Answer (score 1):

El trigger esta bien:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_venta` AFTER
INSERT
    ON
    `detalle` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE
    productos
SET
    stock = stock -new.cantidad
where
    id = id
```

En mi caso, las tablas son "detalle" y "productos" y ambas tienen "id" como campo llave. La tabla productos contiene el campo stock y la tabla detalle el campo cantidad.

Al insertar una nueva compra en detalle, se resta uno en productos.
Saludos!

Comment: Ahora bien, lo que se necesita es un procedimiento que no deje pasar la venta si solo queda determinada cantidad de productos. Por ejemplo, si solo queda 1 en el stock.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER DemoDos.restarStock 
AFTER INSERT ON INCLUYE FOR EACH ROW
Update PRODUCTO
set PRODUCTO.STOCK = PRODUCTO.STOCK - NEW.CANTIDAD_ENTREGADA
where PRODUCTO.ID_PRODUCTO = ID_PRODUCTO;
```

CORREGIDO SE QUITA EL `NEW` DE LA ULTIMA LINEA